# Migrating multiple iPhoto libraries to Photos

Tags: macos, photos.app, migration

I've put off upgrading to El-Capitan because doing so will kill off iPhoto; I've been using it since it came out more than 10 years ago. I'd like to migrate to the new Photos app but am not sure how it will work. Here's my scenario:

- About 15 iPhoto libraries
- Some organised by albums, others by events

What I'd like to achieve:

- Consolidate multiple iPhoto libraries into a single Photos library file/bundle
- Not lose the organisation I've put together (albums/events), preferably preserving the order (albums/events sorted by date, not by name)
- Deletion of my old iPhoto libraries after the above consolidation
- All photo metadata copied across (timestamps, geolocation, exif, etc)

How do I go about achieving this?

(Assume infinite hard drive space, unused aperture installation, 600 GB photos)

Comment: I found [this page](http://www.macrumors.com/how-to/how-to-transfer-photos-from-iphoto-to-photos/) @ MacRumors to be very helpful.

Comment: But that page explicitly says:
"There is no tool within the Photos app to combine multiple libraries into one library, so if you have more than one, you're going to need to work with each library separately or use alternate means to combine them."

Comment: I think http://www.macworld.com/article/2909654/software-photography/how-to-import-merge-and-consolidate-your-libraries-in-photos-for-os-x.html gets much closer, but also offers no definitive answer. The easiest way is probably to first merge iPhoto libraries using iPhoto Library Manager, and _then_ migrate to Photos. But if you've already migrated one library… that doesn't help you.